# plink Unable to read from standard input: The handle is invalid

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, plink

Batch file on WS 2008R2 Enterprise SP1, calling plink.exe (v.0.70.0.0), executing in ubuntu 16.04.4, intermittent failure Unable to read from standard input: The handle is invalid.

```
echo -e "youGuessedIt\n" | sudo -S nginx -t -c /home/userNoOne/Documents/nginx.conf &> /home/userNoOne/Documents/nginxResult.txt 
echo -e "youGuessedIt\n" | sudo -S tail /var/log/nginx/error.log.1 >> /home/userNoOne/Documents/nginxResult.txt
echo -e "youGuessedIt\n" | sudo -S tail /var/log/nginx/error.log >> /home/userNoOne/Documents/nginxResult.txt
```

There is a known bug with Plink.exe that documents this failure. I'm looking for the simplest work-around:
https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/win-plink-stdin-handle-invalid.html

Comment: Looks like you are using BASH.  The `echo` command builtin to `cmd.exe` does not have an `-e` option. Please adjust your tags accordingly.

Comment: Not using BASH. The batch file works most of the time. Fails intermittently.

Comment: Windows batch files are executed by `cmd.exe`.  As I stated in my previous comment, the `ECHO` command that is builtin to `cmd.exe` does not have an `-e` option to interpret backslash escape sequences.

Comment: The example code above runs in ubuntu, but was auto generated from a windows batch file.